# How can I modify values of an array passed to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11, encryption

I'm a C++ beginner and I'm stuck on my course assignment because I can't wrap my head around how to modify values of an array passed to a function.
Honestly, we haven't reached the topic about arrays yet in class, but I recall some basic functionalities related to them and I wanted to solve the exercise using arrays because it's surely a smarter way to do it then the easy version of the assignment without them (that I've already solved). I've looked online for some references but clearly I'm missing something important.

The assignment states:

In this exercise you’ll investigate a simple scheme for encrypting and decrypting data. A company that wants to send data over the Internet has asked  you to write a program that will encrypt the data so that it may be transmitted more securely. All the data is transmitted as four-digit integers. Your application should read a four-digit integer entered by the user and encrypt it as follows:

- Replace each digit with the result of adding 7 to the digit and getting the remainder after dividing the new value by 10.
- Then swap the first digit with the third, and swap the second digit with the fourth.
- Then print the encrypted integer.

And my attempt is this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "encrypt.h"
#include <iostream>

const size_t size{4};


int main () {
    int arrEncrypt[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    swap(arrEncrypt[size]);
    encrypt(arrEncrypt[size]);
    printArr(arrEncrypt[size]);
}
```

**encrypt.h**

```
#ifndef ENCRYPT_H
#define ENCRYPT_H


void encrypt(int a[]);
void swap(int a[]);
void printArr(int a[]);


#endif
```

**encrypt.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "encrypt.h"

const size_t num{4};


// Replace each digit with the result of adding 7 to the digit and getting the remainder after dividing the new value by 10. 
void encrypt(int arr[::num]) {

    for (int k = 0; k < ::num; k++) {
        arr[k] = (arr[k] + 7) % 10;
    }

}

// Then swap the first digit with the third, and swap the second digit with the fourth.
void swap(int arr[::num]) {

    int box[1] = {0};
    for (int k = 0; k < (::num / 2); k++) {
        box[1] = arr[k];
        arr[k] = arr[k+2];     
        arr[k+2] = box[1];  
    }

    box[1] = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[2];
    arr[2] = box[1];

    box[1] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = arr[3];
    arr[3] = box[1]; 

}

// Then print the encrypted integer. 
void printArr(int arr[::num]) {
    
    for (int k = 0; k < ::num; k++) {
        std::cout << arr[k] << " ";
    }

}
```

The swap function has some problems in the algorithm probably because I tried printing the for loop output and I get just one random value, while the bit manually written is working fine. I don't know why.

This program clearly doesn't work because every time I pass the array to a function it is always the one declared in main and not an array modified by the functions. I tried pointing to the array passed to the functions but I think I messed it up because I got a bunch of errors - moreover, I've read that taking the address of a built-in array to pass it to a function is not needed and I can simply pass the built-in array’s name because the called function can modify all the elements of an array in the caller, unless the function precedes the corresponding built-in array parameter with const to indicate that the elements should not be modified. But I don't get why in my program it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for anyone who would take their time to help me out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: `box[1]` is out-of-range for `int box[1] = {0};`. Allocate enough elements or stop using an array here because it looks you are using only one element.

Comment: I'll fix it right away, thank you!

Comment: Please don't break question by editing.

Comment: Why swapping twice. Once with a loop then again manually...?

Comment: Because the for loop wasn't working as a result of the array not passed properly to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can't be passed to a function by value, only by reference or pointer.  In your case, a parameter like `int a[]` is really just syntax sugar for a pointer `int *a`.  But you are not actually calling the functions with a pointer, you are indexing into `arrEncrypt` and passing an individual `int` instead (using an index that is out of range!).

Get rid of the array indexing at the call sites. An array *decays* into a pointer to its 1st element when it is referred to by just its name.

Also, such parameters don't carry size information, so you have to pass the array size explicitly in a separate parameter.

Try this instead:

```
#include "encrypt.h"

const size_t size{4};

int main () {
    int arrEncrypt[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    swap(arrEncrypt, size);
    encrypt(arrEncrypt, size);
    printArr(arrEncrypt, size);
}
```

encrypt.h

```
#ifndef ENCRYPT_H
#define ENCRYPT_H

void encrypt(int a[], int size);
void swap(int a[], int size);
void printArr(int a[], int size);

#endif
```

encrypt.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "encrypt.h"

// Replace each digit with the result of adding 7 to the digit and getting the remainder after dividing the new value by 10. 
void encrypt(int arr[], int size) {
    if (!arr || size < 0) throw invalid_argument("");
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        arr[k] = (arr[k] + 7) % 10;
    }
}

// Then swap the first digit with the third, and swap the second digit with the fourth.
void swap(int arr[], int size) {
    if (!arr || size < 4) throw invalid_argument("");
    int box;

    for (int k = 0; k < (size / 2); k++) {
        box = arr[k];
        arr[k] = arr[k+2];     
        arr[k+2] = box;
    }

    box = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[2];
    arr[2] = box;

    box = arr[1];
    arr[1] = arr[3];
    arr[3] = box;
}

// Then print the encrypted integer. 
void printArr(int arr[], int size) {    
    if (!arr) throw invalid_argument("");
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        std::cout << arr[k] << " ";
    }
}
```

---

That being said, consider using `std::vector` instead, eg:

```
#include "encrypt.h"

int main () {
    std::vector<int> arrEncrypt = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    swap(arrEncrypt);
    encrypt(arrEncrypt);
    printArr(arrEncrypt);
}
```

encrypt.h

```
#ifndef ENCRYPT_H
#define ENCRYPT_H

#include <vector>

void encrypt(std::vector<int> &a);
void swap(std::vector<int> &a);
void printArr(const std::vector<int> &a);


#endif
```

encrypt.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "encrypt.h"

// Replace each digit with the result of adding 7 to the digit and getting the remainder after dividing the new value by 10. 
void encrypt(std::vector<int> &arr) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < arr.size(); k++) {
        arr[k] = (arr[k] + 7) % 10;
    }
}

// Then swap the first digit with the third, and swap the second digit with the fourth.
void swap(std::vector<int> &arr) {
    if (arr.size() < 4) throw invalid_argument("");
    for (size_t k = 0; k < (a.size() / 2); k++) {
        std::swap(arr[k], arr[k+2]);
    }
    std::swap(arr[0], arr[2]);
    std::swap(arr[1], arr[3]);
}

// Then print the encrypted integer. 
void printArr(const std::vector<int> &arr) {    
    for (size_t k = 0; k < arr.size(); k++) {
        std::cout << arr[k] << " ";
    }
}
```

---

Or `std::array`, eg:

```
#include "encrypt.h"

int main () {
    std::array<int, size> arrEncrypt = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    swap(arrEncrypt);
    encrypt(arrEncrypt);
    printArr(arrEncrypt);
}
```

encrypt.h

```
#ifndef ENCRYPT_H
#define ENCRYPT_H

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// Replace each digit with the result of adding 7 to the digit and getting the remainder after dividing the new value by 10. 
template<typename T, size_t N>
void encrypt(std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        arr[k] = (arr[k] + 7) % 10;
    }
}

// Then swap the first digit with the third, and swap the second digit with the fourth.
template<typename T, size_t N>
void swap(std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    if (N < 4) throw invalid_argument("");
    for (size_t k = 0; k < (N / 2); k++) {
        std::swap(arr[k], arr[k+2]);
    }
    std::swap(arr[0], arr[2]);
    std::swap(arr[1], arr[3]);
}

// Then print the encrypted integer. 
template<typename T, size_t N>
void printArr(const std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        std::cout << arr[k] << " ";
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: You are still using out-of-range element `box[1]` in your function `swap()`

Comment: @MikeCAT I saw that, fixed

Comment: It is best to catch an ellipsis and throw something else.

Comment: You explanation is exactly what I needed, everything is much more clear and I finally get what I was getting wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: @QuentinUK I wasn't suggesting to actually *throw* `...` literally (which is impossible anyway), that was just a placeholder to mean "throw *something* here...". But whatever, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

- The arguments `arrEncrypt[size]` in the function `main()` is bad because

  - It is out-of-range because the array `arrEncrypt` has only `size` elements and its valid indice are `0` to `size-1`.
  - The functions are expecting pointers, but an integer is passed.
- The element `box[1]` used in the function `swap()` is out-of-range because the array `box` has only one element. Since it looks you are using only the element `box[1]` from the array `box`, you should stop using array here and instead of that you should use simple variable `box`.

In the function `main()`, you should pass the array (or a pointer to the first element of the array converted from the array) to the function:

```cpp
int main () {
    int arrEncrypt[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    swap(arrEncrypt);
    encrypt(arrEncrypt);
    printArr(arrEncrypt);
}
```

In the function `swap()`, you should stop using out-of-range "element":

```cpp
void swap(int arr[::num]) {

    int box = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < (::num / 2); k++) {
        box = arr[k];
        arr[k] = arr[k+2];     
        arr[k+2] = box;  
    }

    box = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[2];
    arr[2] = box;

    box = arr[1];
    arr[1] = arr[3];
    arr[3] = box; 

}
```

Comment: `int arr[::num]` is not valid, even if `::num` is a compile-time constant, it will be ignored in a parameter declaration anyway. Just use `int arr[]` instead, which is really just `int *arr`

Comment: I've modified my code and now the swap function is working perfectly. The box array was useless and I messed up all the ranges of the arrays, but now I've a better insight of how arrays work so thank you a lot!